# Can Google Analytics code snippet be placed in the footer rather than the head on Angular sites?

Tags: google-analytics, angular.js

As per common practice, UA-codes should always be placed on head section of the website.

But in this case, our web developers would like to place the ua-code on the footer of the site coz "it's an angular site".

Does placing the UA-code on footer of an angular site works like a normal site that has the UA-code on the head section?

Comment: See also: [Is there any benefit of Google Analytics asynchronous tracking code if it isn't placed in the <head>?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/721/is-there-any-benefit-of-google-analytics-asynchronous-tracking-code-if-it-isnt)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get some features, such as real-time reporting, or Google Webmaster Tools verification, unless the code sits within the `<head>`. The whole point of the asynchronous code is that it loads and works while the rest of the page is loading. There is no UX risk from placing it within the , and it is best-practice to do so. source: [Google Analytics Support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en)

When troubleshoting Google Analytics, the most common tracker setup mistake and the first thing to verify is if the code is right after the  tag. source: [Google Analytics Support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009683?hl=en&ref_topic=1008079)